# Creating a trigger to check for status,

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with companies, and one of the columns is their status, which can be active as A or deactivated as D, and i am trying to make a trigger to check if the company is active so they can pay taxes or deactivated and they wont be bothered.

```
CREATE TRIGGER StatusCheck
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON Companies C
REFERENCING NEW AS N --row to be added
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN c.status <> 'A' or c.status <>'D';
ABORT TRANSACTION
```

This clearly doesnt work, but how can i do this, because i have been overthinking about this and now i think i need some help.

Comment: A trigger is not needed use a check constraint

Comment: That was my initial thought but my requirement is to be done with a trigger to make sure that i insert only in active companies.

Comment: A trigger is the worst solution to that problem. A check constraint is much more efficient.

Comment: I think that is for learning purposes.

Comment: could you give me some help with check constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct and most efficient way to implement such a requirement is a [check constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS)

```
alter table companies
   add constraint check_status check (status in ('A', 'D'));
```

---

If you are forced to use a trigger:

You create trigger statement has two errors:

The first one is a syntax error: there is no `abort transaction` option in the [`create trigger`][1] statement.

The second one is a logical error: the condition `c.status <> 'A' or c.status <>'D'` is essentially always true. What you want there is an `AND` condition: "*if the status value is different than A **and** different than D...*".

However a complete trigger definition in Postgres consists of a [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) and the `create trigger` statement attaching that function to a table trigger.

Inside the function you would need to throw an exception to abort the transaction:

```
create function check_company_status()
  returns trigger
as
$$
begin
  if not new.status in ('A', 'D') then 
    raise 'Invalid valid for status specified';
  end if;
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Now that we have a trigger function, we can attach that to a trigger on the table:

```
create trigger check_status_trigger
   before insert or update
   on companies
   for each row
   execute procedure check_company_status();
```

It's important to define that as a `BEFORE` trigger.

---

Note that neither of those solutions will prevent NULL values in that column. If you also want to prevent NULL, the column should be defined as `NOT NULL`